# Adding entry type using setContentFromPost

Tags: plugin-development, usermodel, craft2

I'm creating a new user using `$user->setContentFromPost()`. It all works fine except I can't attach an entry to an Entries field.

```
$user = new UserModel();
$user->username         = $email;
$user->email            = $email;
$user->unverifiedEmail  = $email;

$user->setContentFromPost(array(
  'companyName' => $admin->companyName, 
  'companyId' => $admin->companyId, 
  'partnerManager[]' => $admin->partnerManager[0]->id
));
```

This will create user but the `partnerManager` Entries field will be empty. I've tried a few different syntax variations, but none of them seem to work:

```
'fields[partnerManager][]' => $admin->partnerManager[0]->id
'partnerManager' => $admin->partnerManager[0]->id
'partnerManager[0]' => $admin->partnerManager[0]->id
```

How to fill this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships are always added as arrays of IDs, even if you are only relating a single element:

```
$user->setContentFromPost(array(
    'companyName' => $admin->companyName, 
    'companyId' => $admin->companyId, 
    'partnerManager' => array($admin->partnerManager[0]->id)
));
```